# How to "freeze" a parallel program

Tags: parallelization, procedural-programming

I wrote a program, parallelized it (using `ParallelDo[]`, `SetSharedVariable[]` etc.), and enjoyed the wonderful speedup. Nevertheless, the program may take hours to days in a real-world scenario. Much simplified, the components resemble this:

```
SetSharedVariable[results];
results = {};
ParallelDo[
  Block[{currentResult}, 
    CriticalSection[{resultslock}, currentResult = i^2; 
      AppendTo[results, currentResult];];];, {i, {a, g, c, f, w}}];
```

I came up with the idea to press a key during execution to freeze the internal state and store it in a file to resume computation at a later moment by loading the file -- in other words: to store which elements of ParallelDo were worked on, which is the current element, which are the values of shared variables.

The single iterations will be relatively autonomous (no side effects besides shared variables, no time-dependence, and external resources always available), but it would be nice despite not being necessary if it would work with nested loops. It would be o. k. to completely recalculate the current iteration, if it is the innermost parallel loop.

It very much looks like a solved problem and would take some time and care to implement. Does there already exist such a solution/package? (One possible implementation method would be to decorate (as in Python): `Store@ParallelDo`)

PS: Solutions with `Sow[]` and `Reap[]` instead of `AppendTo[]` are warmly welcomed as well, I do not know their internal state variables.

Comment: *I came up with the idea to press a key during execution to freeze the internal state ...* I wouldn't do it that way, it requires that you write code to freeze the internal state at any arbitrary point during execution.  I would write the state to a checkpoint file at regular intervals.  If you need to interrupt the computation you would then restart from the last checkpoint.

Comment: Besides saving intermediate results, you might also be interested in speeding up your code. Just to give you some hints in that direction, consider using Compile[] for low level functions that you have written, and using Map[] instead of nested loops. Also, AppendTo[] might be really slow depending on the specific data, if that's the case consider using Sow[] and Reap[] instead (or reshape your code to avoid massive use of AppendTo)